# Insert rows in section by date

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have an array containing fixtures of football matches like this:

```
[fixtures addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:date,@"date", time, @"time", competition_id,@"competition_id", home, @"home", away, @"away", nil]];
```

Then i have an array which contain all the dates no duplicates. This array is also the array for the sections.

```
[sections addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:date,@"date", nil]];
```

My question is then how will the numberOfRowsInSection & cellForRowAtIndexPath look so all the fixtures where the date is equal to the sections date and then show it under the sections?

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= sections.count-1; i++)
    {
        NSArray *filteredArray = [fixtures filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date == %@",sections[i][@"date"]]];
        if(section==i) {
            return filteredArray.count;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What I generally do is create an array for all the sections, then for the array element for each section use another array containing the entries for that section.  Make the zeroth element in the inner array contain the info for the section header.  Takes some effort to set up, but it maps very cleanly to a tables sections/rows.

Comment: The problem is that fixtures changes dynamically.

Comment: So change the array structure and do `reloadData`.  Which is what you need to do when the model changes, regardless.

Comment: But how can i dynamically create an array for each section, because there is not always the same number of sections.

Comment: If the number of sections changes you add or remove inner arrays as needed.  NSMutableArray lets you easily add/remove entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood the question - you need convenient way to filter your `fixtures` array for date from `sections`. If `i` is section number - `sections[i][@"date"]`.

Following code will do it:

```
NSArray *filteredArray = [fixtures filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date == %@",sections[i][@"date"]]];
NSLog(@"count = %lul", (unsigned long)filteredArray.count); // Number of items matching
NSLog([filteredArray description]); // Matching items
```

UPDATE:

numberOfRowsInSection method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSArray *filteredArray = [fixtures filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date == %@",sections[section][@"date"]]];
    return filteredArray.count;
}
```

Comment: This was kind of what i needed: i've used your method in numberofrowsinsection. how come it returns: control may reach end of non-void function. You can see it in question?

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround, make `fixtures` an `NSMutableDictionary` with keys similar to value of `date` in `section`.

Then try like this: (psuedocode)

```
  // Inside cell for row at index path delegate
  {
  NSMutableDictionary *fixtureForSectionDate = [fixtures valueForKey:[[sections allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];

   // do stuff with fixture data
  }
```

Use the same  way to get number of rows `numberOfRowsInSection`. Hope it makes sense.